# Colour coding calendar entries based on conditions SharePoint 2013

Tags: calendar

I have a calendar view in a library and I want to be able to change to colour of the calendar entry if status is Approved and if Due Date is overdue. I have tried highlighting rows using CSR found on an other post in here but it doesn't work for Calendar views. 
Is there a way to do that? Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks